# How to include all parameters of a standard HST component in child component?

Tags: java, inheritance, hippocms

A lot of my custom components extends the [EssentialsListComponent](http://www.onehippo.org/library/setup/hst-components/list-component.html). The same standard HST component has a lot of useful parameters such as `pageSize` and `sortOrder` (input through the Console) which I currently have to handle individually in my classes. This process is tedious and prone to human error.

How can I apply all the standard parameters at once to my HST query in my custom HST component? For example, something like the following would be lovely:

```
@Override
    protected <T extends EssentialsDocumentListComponentInfo> HstQuery buildQuery(HstRequest request, T paramInfo,
                                                                                  HippoBean scope) {
scope = request.getRequestContext().getSiteContentBaseBean();
try {
HstQuery hstQuery = request.getRequestContext().getQueryManager().createQuery(scope);
hstQuery.applyParameters(paramInfo);// paramInfo should already includes pageSize, sortOrder etc. right?
} catch (Exception e) {
}
}
```

Comment: In a general Java speaking, would this be copying all public properties from one object to another?

Comment: First, I'm not sure if the component parameters in question here are the same as the public properties you are referring to

Comment: Secondly, the parent class has a way of putting the parameters into the final HST query. Let's say it's done via a method `applyCompParams`, why can't my class call something like `super.applyCompParams`?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the `EssentialsDocumentListComponentInfo` interface, suppose `MyDocumentListComponentInfo` which is also an interface.
On the `MyDocumentListComponentInfo` interface override the methods you want to have default values such as `pageSize` and `sortOrder`.

Lets say you want the pageSize to have a default value of 20 instead of 10. For this you would use the code below:

```
@Parameter(name = "pageSize", required = true, defaultValue = "20", displayName = "Page size", description = "Nr of items per page")
int getPageSize();
```

With this you do not need to declare the property in the Console, unless you want a custom value.

Now in the components you extend, declare the following annotation above the class declaration:

```
@ParametersInfo(type = MyDocumentListComponentInfo.class)
```

Now your code should work fine and you have less parameters to configure every time.

Answer (score 0):

see: http://www.onehippo.org/library/concepts/component-development/hstcomponent-parametersinfo-annotation.html

If you extend a component you inherit its parameters. |If you set it up to inherit in the hst configuration you can access those parameters. You can also reuse or extend existing parameterinfo interfaces to make cleaner code. If a parameter isn't included in the parameterinfo then you can still refer to it by name.

Note the documentation link is for version 10. If you need documentation on 7.9 or older then click the history link at the top of the article.